# SharePoint Workflow Error -The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: 2013, workflow, visual-studio, sharepoint-addin

I have created a SharePoint 2013 Workflow in Visual Studio 2012. This workflow is activated when a list item is modified.

Once the list item modified, the workflow shows as the started. But on clicking "started" or "workflow name", it throws an error:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>
> **Stack Trace**
>
> [KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.]
>      System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) +14122715
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowInstanceProvider.GetRetryMessage(WorkflowInstance instance) +936
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowInstanceProvider.GetInstance(Guid instanceId) +463
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.ApplicationPages.WrkStatPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +611
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178

Edit:
Prior to the above error, an http 401 error (Token contains invalid signature) was thrown on workflow initiation. After following the steps mentioned [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/projectsupport/archive/2014/01/13/sharepoint-2013-workflow-token-contains-invalid-signature.aspx), it started throwing the above error.

Comment: have you checked the uls-logs?

Comment: @Gwny Same message as mentioned in stack trace.

Comment: is the list stored in the same site as the workflow?

Comment: @Gwny Yes. Both list and workflow are stored in the same SharePoint App web.

Comment: you wrote that you created the workflow in visual studio, are you able to deploy in debug mode?

Comment: @Gwny: Yes. That is also successful. Workflow is also initiated when an item is modified. It shows as started and when i click on it, it throws the above mentioned error.

Comment: when I had this error last time it was because the item I wanted to retreive from the list was null. Does the workflow do any tasks or just stay in state 'started' with this error when you click on it?

Comment: @Gwny list is not null. Yes, the workflow stays in "started" state and throws the error when i click it.

Comment: the question is, what does your workflow do? maybe the problem is there

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error, but it begin appers after re-installing workflow manager on the another server and applying updates. After two days of searching, i've decided to remove proxy and run Register-SPWorkflowService with ScopeName parameter value different from "Sharepoint". See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn411563(v=office.15).aspx).
I recommend to save all your workflows before taking this action.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that too but didn't work. In the end, i reconfigured Domain Controller and Windows App Fabric and the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same issue after installing recommend MS Updates.

It seams there is issue with recent MS update for SharePoint i.e. KB2880998

Hotfix to fix the issue is : KB2880963 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2880963)

It has resolved my issue.